# Microsoft Windows server monitoring tools

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, monitoring, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm more of a developer then an IT guy and I was wondering if there are any existing Microsof tools for monitoring servers and potentially SQL Server.

We have access to MSDN so anything created by Microsoft would be preferred.

Comment: Be careful of what you mean by "access to MSDN" Depending on your level, you may only have rights to use certain things for demo/test, not for production use.

Last I looked, Gold Partners only had a small handful of licenses for SCOM.

Comment: use nagios, scom is for large environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check out a product called SCOM from microsoft.  Depending on if you have a virtual environment or not the pricing is pretty respectable these days.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [**System Center**](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/overview.aspx) products, specifically Operations Manager.  It's available to download via MSDN, depending on your subscription level, however I don't know to what extent you'll be able to use it in production since MSDN only provides for single user testing purposes.